# Confusion about suffix type of ''like''

Tags: suffixes

Ex:

1)The illness causes chest pains and ***flu-like symptoms*** [suffix type of ''like'']

2)The illness causes chest pains and ***symptoms like flu***. [preposition type of ''like'']

İs there any difference between these two sentence in the meaning in nuance and are both sentences correct grammatically?

Comment: The flu is not a symptom. It's an actual disease. That's why *symptoms like the flu* is already a nonsensical phrase.

Comment: The OP didn't say that flu was a symptom; he said "flu-like symptoms" and "symptoms like flu". Both are fine.

Comment: Alright. Maybe I'm reading it wrong.

Comment: "flu-like symptoms" is more elegant than "symptoms that are like those of the flu." symptoms like flu is wrong. flu is not a symptom; it's an illness. symptoms like having a runny nose, fever, and arching bones: those are symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

There is normally no difference.  *X-like* is simply an abbreviated way to say *like the/an X*, and is often preferred because it is less *wordy*.

Example:

> She habitually wore an expression **like a cat**, of self-satisfied complacency.
>   She habitually wore a **catlike** expression of self-satisfied complacency.
>
> She processed the forms with an efficiency **like a machine**, working through the entire stack in less than an hour.
>   She processed the forms with **machine-like** efficiency, working through the entire stack in less than an hour.

Note the construction "X-like" can be used with nearly anything:

> He pitched his plan to the group of investors with **Trump-like** bravado.

(Edit) As stangdon's comment mentions, be careful of confusing the different meanings of "like".  For example:

> They **like** a good movie.

is different from

> They **are like** a good movie.

The comment references a popular English grammar pun:

> Time flies like an arrow; fruit flies like a banana.

The second part can be interpreted two ways, either "fruit flies (the insect) like bananas" or "fruit flies (through the air) like a banana".

(Edit 2) Lambie's objection is that while *flu-like symptoms* is fine, *symptoms like a/the flu* is not.  Strictly speaking, I agree.  "The flu" is an illness, and is not directly comparable to the *symptoms* of an illness.

The correct expression should be something like:

> symptoms **like those that you get from** the flu

That being said, many English speakers will shorten this to *symptoms like the flu*.

Comment: Although we should note that in a lot of contexts "like a Y" can be ambiguous, as in "Fruit flies like a banana".

Comment: There is an error in the understanding of phrase "symptoms like flu"; No one has dealt with this grammar point. The two expressions are not the same here in this medical context. A cat-like expression may be an expression like a cat. Yes.